# How to turn link at specific angle in the middle in force graph

Tags: d3.js

I have a simple force graph in which I need 135 degree angle in the middle of links. It should look like the image embed in below link.

Sample force graph
[image]

I think this is how it can be solved. I have source and target points for a link. From those two points I can calculate the middle point of link (using midpoint formula). Now all I have to do is find the another point which is little away from mid point of link and have equal distance from other two points so that it will make a certain angle. I am not sure how to find this point.Below image can show you the illustration. I need to find point F as shown in below image.I am using SVG path for links.

Clearly there can be other ways to solve this problem and if there is any please let me know.

illustration of logic
[image]

Comment: just calculate: the height of a triangle with top angle 135 and a given base length, (tip use 1/2 base length)

Comment: Thank you rioV8 for your answer. I got the height of triangle. Now the question is how to find the coordinates of point f?